# A boxed value is unboxed and then immediately reboxed

Tags: java, findbugs, autoboxing

I am getting the Findugs error "A boxed value is unboxed and then immediately reboxed".

This is the Code:

```
Employee emp = new Employee()
Long lmt = 123L;

emp.setLimit(Long.valueOf(lmt));
```

In this, Employee `limit` field is of type `Long`. Could you please let me know what is the error?

Comment: Is there a reason that you're using Long and not long variables and parameters? Since the limit parameter is a Long, why not simply pas `lmt` into the method? Why call `Long.valueOf(lmg)`?

Answer (score 22):

The problem is that you're converting `Long` -> `long` -> `Long`.

So in the background:

1. `Long.valueOf(lmt)` converts `Long` to `long`
2. `emp.setLimit(<long>);` converts `long` to `Long`  again

As of Java 5 autoboxing happens => your code should look like this:

```
Employee emp = new Employee()
Long lmt = 123L;

emp.setLimit(lmt);
```

or even:

```
Employee emp = new Employee()
long lmt = 123L;

emp.setLimit(lmt);
```

Answer (score 4):

That happens because `Long.valueOf(long)` will unbox your `lmt` from `Long` to `long`, just to get a `Long` again. As you said that `limit` is a `Long`, you don't need to use `Long.valueOf`, just use the var:

```
emp.setLimit(lmt);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
emp.setLimit(Long.valueOf(lmt));
```

`Long.valueOf` takes a `long` value, but you pass a `Long` value -- mandating unboxing. Immediately afterward, however, `Long.valueOf` re-boxes the value and the expression evaluates to a `Long` again. FindBugs detects the unnecessary conversion chain `Long` -> `long` -> `Long`.